# jOOQ Connection Pool Release Pattern with HikariDataSource

Tags: jooq, hikaricp

Is this the correct way to release the connection back to the pool

```
HikariDataSource ds = ...;
final Connection sqlConn = ds.getConnection();
final DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(sqlConn, SQLDialect.DERBY);
  // DO JOOQ QUERIES HERE       
ds.evictConnection(sqlConn);
```

Just want to make sure this right as my connections do not get re-cycled if I do not call evictConnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, simply calling `sqlConn.close()` will release the connection back to the pool.

When HikariCP, or any pool, returns you a connection from `getConnection()`, what it is actually returning is a proxy object that intercepts the `close()` call and returns the connection to the pool instead of actually closing it.

`evictConnection()` is a method that is rarely used.  It is a method to forcefully close the connection to the database and evict the connection from the pool.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [brettw's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31306021/521799)'s answer, which explains the semantics of `close()` compared to `evictConnection()`, I'd say you could also simply let jOOQ wrap your `DataSource` directly:

```
HikariDataSource ds = ...;
final DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(ds, SQLDialect.DERBY);
  // DO JOOQ QUERIES HERE
```

jOOQ will internally use a [`DataSourceConnectionProvider`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DataSourceConnectionProvider.html), which takes care of closing each connection after every query.

Comment: @VladimirDzhuvinov: Let's say, it doesn't do anything to prevent it. Threadsafety is usually governed by your `ConnectionProvider` implementation. In the case of this answer, the `DataSourceConnectionProvider` will in turn delegate the thread safety question to the `DataSource`, which is usually thread safe if you use a standard implementation like a connection pool, Java EE or spring implementation

Comment: @LukasEder If I wrap a pool like that in your answer JOOQ is taking Connection objects as needed and closes them when needed (which in turn returns connection to the pool) when I use that DSLContext to write queries?

Comment: @SašaŠijak: Yes